# I can't get the total sum from the database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to get the total amount of fine from my database and show it to my `lblFine.Text`, but their is always an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Student ID' to data type int.'

Here is my code:

```
public void CountFine()
{
    cn.Open();
    cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(totalFine) FROM tblFine where studentID = '" + lblStudID.Text + "'", cn);
    lblFine.Text = cm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the type of `studentID` in your database is integer so you need to convert the value of your `lblStudentId` to int. However this kind of string concatenation are open to SQL Injection attacks. You should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and also to get rid of errors:

```
cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(totalFine) FROM tblFine where studentID = @studentId", cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentId", Convert.ToInt32(lblStudID.Text));
```

Although specify the type directly and use the Value property is more better than AddWithValue::

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@studentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(lblStudID.Text);
```

Read more here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot to leave the lblStudID to blank.

Comment: Also, can you give me some snippets on how to make a parameterized queries?

Comment: @kemchan I have already shown how you can use the parameterized queries. Do it with `studentID = @studentId` and `cm.Parameters.Add`.

Comment: @SalahAkbari Don't recommend or even demonstrate [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) because of the problems it has

Comment: @SMor Yes, that's why I have included a better solution with `Add` in my answer. But a good explanation would be better to be added in order OP find out more regarding that, updated my answer.